# Wait to initiate controller until tab is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of tabs within my Angular app which are each their own directive. The controller associated with each of these directives contains an `init()` function, so each controller calls the functions within its respective controller's `init()` function on page load.

What I want to do is only fire off the visible tab's `init()` function on page load. Some of the additional tabs contain large amounts of data, and it's a waste to load them on page load if the user never ends up clicking on them anyways.

Could I simply attach an `ng-click` to the additional tabs and only fire off their respective `init()` functions when the tab is clicked (like below), or is there a better approach?

```
<tabset>
  <tab>
    <gm-players></gm-players>
  </tab>
  <tab ng-click="loadGames()">
    <gm-games></gm-games>
  </tab>
  <tab ng-click="loadLeagues()">
    <gm-leagues></gm-leagues>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

My possible approach: The controller associated with `gm-players` fires on page load, controllers associated with `gm-games` and `gm-leagues` only fire when respective tab is clicked.

Comment: Hard to help with generalities without seeing some app structure code. Making requests for data on demand such as `ng-click` is not uncommon. Perhaps you need a service you aren't using or implement some caching... too many unknowns

Comment: @charlietfl, added details above.

Comment: if those are angular-ui-bootstrap tabs it already has a `select` attribute that you pass function to for each tab selected `<tab select="loadLeagues()">`

Answer (score 2):

This scenario seems like an excellent fit for [ui-router's](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). This way your controllers are only initialized when the tab they correspond to is open. It keeps things declarative and clean :)

E.g.:

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/games")

  $stateProvider
    .state('games', {
        url: "/games",
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        controller: function($scope){
          console.log('Games initialized');
          $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
        }
    })
    .state('leagues', {
        url: "/leagues",
        templateUrl: "route2.html",
        controller: function($scope){
          console.log('Leagues initialized');
          $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
        }
    })
})
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0yg4IwwbY2AAzNIeSEJ?p=preview)

Comment: demo is broken with invalid state

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, thanks for pointing that out :facepalm:. Fixed!